# List of dictionaries to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I want to do some dict comprehension for better data oranization

**Original Dict:**

```
mach = [{'name': 'Software 1', 'code': 'F105', 'version': '12.70.2', 'size': '115.25 Mb'},
        {'name': 'Software 2', 'code': 'F118', 'version': '12.71.22', 'size': '105.25 Mb'},
        {'name': 'Software 3', 'code': 'F115', 'version': '12.71.22', 'size': '105.25 Mb'},
        ....
        {'name': 'Software x', 'code': 'F120', 'version': '12.71.22', 'size': '105.25 Mb'}]
```

**Needed Output Dict:**

```
    new_mach = {'Software 1': 'F105',
                'Software 2': 'F118',
                'Software 3': 'F115',
                ...
                'Software x': 'F120'}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You'd need some kind of loop

Comment: So you want the pattern of name : code for each dictionary in mach?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy:

```
new_match = {}

for elem in match:
    new_match[elem["name"]] = elem["code"]
```

Comment: The pattern "construct a builtin container, iterate another container, and add elements from the second to the first container" is usually a perfect match for a comprehension.

Comment: yes it's a base structure very useful in lots of situations

Answer (score 3):

You could use a **[dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)**:

```
>>> mach = [
...     {
...         'name': 'Software 1',
...         'code': 'F105',
...         'version': '12.70.2',
...         'size': '115.25 Mb'
...     },
...     {
...         'name': 'Software 2',
...         'code': 'F118',
...         'version': '12.71.22',
...         'size': '105.25 Mb'
...     },
...     {
...         'name': 'Software 3',
...         'code': 'F115',
...         'version': '12.71.22',
...         'size': '105.25 Mb'
...     },
...     {
...         'name': 'Software x',
...         'code': 'F120',
...         'version': '12.71.22',
...         'size': '105.25 Mb'
...     }
... ]
>>>
>>> new_mach = {d['name']: d['code'] for d in mach}
>>> new_mach
{'Software 1': 'F105', 'Software 2': 'F118', 'Software 3': 'F115', 'Software x': 'F120'}
```

Comment: Do this. Accept this as the answer as it is the solution you will see more often as the "pythonic" approach versus a for loop.